# Join temp table with existing query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join

I have 2 queries in SSMS which are executing fine.
I need to join them together, and I'm not sure how to (I'm a beginner at T-SQL).

The first script is pulling data from a database and transforming some of the columns to create my fact table:

```
SELECT 'Policy' As PolicyType,  
PolicyKey = [POLICY_NUMBER] + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [TRNS_MSG_TS], 120),  
"BATCH_ID",   
"HISTORY_ID",   
"POLICY_NUMBER",  
"TRANSACTION_TYPE_CODE",  
"POLICY_STATUS",  
"COVER_WANTED",  
"PACKAGE_TYPE",  
"MIGRATION_INDICATOR",  
"REFERRER_PREFIX",  
"PROCESSOR_PREFIX",  
"INTRODUCER_CHANNEL",  
"INTRODUCER_SUBCHANNEL",  
CAST("POLICY_VERSION_EFFECTIVE_START_DATE" AS DATE) As StartDate,  
CAST("POLICY_EXPIRY_DATE" AS DATE) As PQExpiryDate,  
CAST("CANCELLATION_DATE" AS DATE) As CancellationDate,  
"FINALISED_PREMIUM_AMOUNT",  
"ANNUAL_PREMIUM",  
"TRANSACTIONAL_PREMIUM",  
CAST("TRNS_MSG_TS" AS DATE) As TRNSDate,  
CAST(LOADDATE AS DATE) As LoadDate,  
OFFSET_IND,  
FIX_IND  

FROM Database.dbo."View1"  
WHERE "POLICY_VERSION_EFFECTIVE_START_DATE" >= DATEADD(DAY,-1*DAY(GETDATE())+0,         DATEADD(MONTH,-12,GETDATE()))  
AND OFFSET_IND = 0  
AND FIX_IND = 0  
AND LOADDATE <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

The second script is creating a temp table which I want to use as a mapping table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "POLICY_NUMBER",  
'Policy' as PolicyType,  
CAST(MIN("TRNS_MSG_TS") As Date) As MinDate  

into #FirstTransFlagMap  
FROM Database.dbo."View1"  
Group by "POLICY_NUMBER";  

SELECT PolicyKey = ["POLICY_NUMBER"] + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[MinDate], 120),  
'1' as FirstTransFlag  
FROM #FirstTransFlagMap;
```

What I'm trying to do is join these two scripts together so that the fact table outputs all of the aforementioned columns, along with the FirstTransFlag column where the values are 1 (if the PolicyKeys match) and 0 (if they don't)

Can anyone help me join these two scripts together to get the desired result?

I just can't work out how to format my syntax to join these scripts. First time trying to work with temp tables/fields, and first time trying to join tables together in SSMS

Comment: SSMS is the IDE-like application, not the data engine; what product and version are you using? For example SQL Server (2017) or Azure Synapse.

Comment: Put your second query in a CTE and then join to it in your main query

Comment: @ThomA I'm using SSMS version 2014!

Comment: Again, that's SSMS, not the version or product. What does `PRINT @@VERSION;` return?

Comment: @NickW Thank you for the pointer, I'll look into CTE's today!

Comment: @ThomA sorry, again, I'm extremely beginner level at this, not a lot of understanding of SQL, just having to write queries blind to be honest! I've ran that query and it returned the following:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3-GDR) (KB4057113) - 10.50.6560.0 (X64) 
 Dec 28 2017 15:03:48 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Thanks

Comment: 2008 R2?! That version of SQL Server ran *completely* out of support almost **4 years** ago; you should really be using a (much more) recent version. I, at least, hope you're paying for the Extended Security updates (though if you are, you haven't applied them) for your *Enterprise* instance.

Comment: @ThomA Oh really!? I had no idea of that, although I am unsurprised!! Unfortunately, I have zero control over this type of thing, I'm just a Power BI developer trying to engineer data so that it's fit for the reporting requirements I've been passed, fingers crossed I can get it working

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your temp table is already created you can use it as is. For the first query, you can use CTE (common table expression).

So you would have something like

```
WITH FirstQueryTabularDataCTE (all properties that you need)
AS
(
   FirstQuery
)
SELECT f.Property1 from #FirstTransFlagMap AS f
JOIN FirstQueryTabularDataCTE AS CTE
ON f.Id = CTE.Id
```

Obviously, pseudo code, but should steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I'll take a run at this and see how it turns out! @lostinsarajevo